# Algorithm formation in c language

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, swap

SO i am trying to make a algo that shift element in array when ever 2 is found in array

input `3 4 2 9`,  output `4 2 9 0` this output is needed , I have tried some sort of code but quite confused cause it either copys or it delete the element , output is `3 4 0 9` or anything like that

```
int main() {
    int a[4], i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Enter element: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    
    void dele() {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("%d",i);
            if (a[i] == 2) {
                printf("Ds");
                for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                    printf("DSasdw");
                    a[j+1] = a[j-1];
                    printf("%dww",a[j-1]);
                }
                a[3] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    dele();
    
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you shared is only in C. Why do you added the pyton tag? The description of the alg. is not very clear, If you eplain it better, people can give you more meaningfull answers.

Comment: You could as well have added the Pascal language tag, since it also support nested function, like Python. But C does *not* support it.

Comment: Besides the obvious invalid nested function, please take some time to refresh  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: It looks like you only want a solution for arrays with exactly 4 elements. Can you say more about the use-case for this

Comment: On another couple of notes, the inner loop in the `dele` function will use a negative index if when `i == 0`. Its debug output is also flawed since you don't flush the output, so it might not be shown. And `NULL` is a macro for the null *pointer*, not a "null value" (C has no concept of null values).

Comment: For me the ouput of your code is `3 4 3 0 ` not `3 4 0 9`. And the random prints makes the debug output quite useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will do what you want, from my understanding:

```
void shift_array(int arr[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
      }
      arr[size - 1] = 0;
      i--;
      size--;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int num_elements = 5;
  int a[num_elements], i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    printf("Enter element: ");
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  shift_array(a, num_elements);

  for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    printf(" %d ", a[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This function loops through the array until it finds a 2, then the inner loop shifts it to the left by 1 place and make the last element = 0, then we decrease the counter and the size in order to check the newly shifted element until we finish the whole array.

[image]

Comment: What is your understanding of the OP's problem? What is the problem with the code that the OP is showing? Why would your code solve the problem but the OP's wont? Please don't only post code to be copy-pasted (that too often leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad), also especially not for bad questions like this one. And please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Next time I will improve my answers and I will elaborate what is the problem of the OP code and the ways of fixing it while trying to stay away from the copy-paste code